# using c#'s tickcount to delay a program

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So I'm looking to pause the program for 5 seconds before it continues on to the rest of the program. This is the gist of what i have so far.

```
tickerStart = System.Environment.TickCount;

do
{
//this is part of my own library, it generates a shape in a different window
numbers.AddText(Convert.ToString(number), 100);
}
while (tickerStart < 5000);


numbers.AddRectangle(0, 0, 800, 600, Color.Black);
//This last line simply clears the screen
Console.Readkey();
```

Essentially, i want to generate some text in a different window, and then want to clear it 5 seconds later.

Comment: The value for `tickerStart` never changes in your code so `tickerStart < 5000` will always be `false` or `true`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code that you provided in your question you are not updating `tickerStart` so the condition in the `while` loop will never change.

As a basic fix - but not recommended - you should do something like this:

```
tickerStart = System.Environment.TickCount;

do
{
    numbers.AddText(Convert.ToString(number), 100);
}
while (System.Environment.TickCount - tickerStart < 5000);

numbers.AddRectangle(0, 0, 800, 600, Color.Black);
```

However, this code isn't recommended because it will block the UI-thread so the UI won't update while the code is running.

Instead you need to use some sort of timer to get this done.

I'd recommend using Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "Rx-WinForms" or "Rx-WPF"). I'm assuming Winforms with this code:

```
Observable
    .Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1)) //start immediately, then every 0.1s
    .Take(50) // 5 seconds = 50 x 0.1s
    .ObserveOn(this)
    .Subscribe(
        n => numbers.AddText(Convert.ToString(number), 100), //each timer tick
        () => numbers.AddRectangle(0, 0, 800, 600, Color.Black)); //at end
```

If you're using WPF then the `.ObserveOn(this)` changes to `.ObserveOnDispatcher()`.

Mind you - this won't delay your program. If you do try to delay the UI won't update. So you need to put what ever code needs to run next into the `() => { /* finally */}` code block.